# How to wrap text around an image in ActiveReports 7?

Tags: image, css-float, word-wrap, activereports, componentone

Is anyone aware of a way to get text in an ActiveReport to wrap around an image similar to floating an image to the right using CSS? I want the text to print in the available space to the left of the image, and when there is enough text, to print the full width of the report under the image as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using a RichTextBox to display the text. I cannnot change that because I am displaying HTML rather than text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are working with different report items (RichTextBox for displaying text and Picture control for dispalying image), then the requested behavior cannot be implemented. This is due to the reason that a report has a static design and a single control cannot have varying width.

A workaround to implement this is to make use of the RTF file that has both text and image aligned in the desired manner. And load this RTF in the RichTextBox control in report.

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I'm not sure if I can do that in this case, but thank you for the idea! I think I am just out of luck this time.